# Allow a user to resize a block vertically and have everything below it push back/forward

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Essentially I'm trying to build a "spacer" block. Meaning a user can drag the bottom of the block and bring it up or down and everything under it would resize. For a quick MS drawing this is what I mean
[image]

An idea I had to was just put a text area block, this actually works perfectly and exactly as I need [as shown here](https://i.gyazo.com/3bb97c99ca7e7536defe893c0f16e1ff.mp4), but it's a text area... I just need an empty block with maybe a small border and text inside saying "Resize me" in big letters in the middle of the block.

If anyone has an efficient way to accomplish this I would appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

While the textarea block almost gets you there I think you should make this from scratch.

Create a few divs

```
<div>Lorem ipsum<div>
<div>Lorem ipsum<div>
<div id="resize">Resize me!<div>
<div>Lorem ipsum<div>
```

Create an event listener on the resize div. [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp) [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener)

When the user triggers the event listener calculate how much the user's mouse moved

Increase height of element by that amount.

Answer (score 0):

There's a CSS property called `resize`. It doesn't work on Internet Explorer but other browsers support it. It can be set to `none`, `both`, `horizontal`, `vertical`, `initial`, or `inherit`. For your purposes, you'll be using `resize: vertical`. You should also use `overflow: auto` on the object you're resizing (I'm not sure why, but it seems to be required).
HTML:

```
<div>
<p>Content</p>
</div>
<div class="resizable">
<p>Resize Me!</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>Content</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>More Content</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: text-center;
}
.resizable {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: text-center;
  min-height: 3em;
  border: 1px solid;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

You can drag the div's height by dragging its bottom right corner.